# How to integrate PHP code with iOS code?

Tags: php, ios, xcode

This question might have broad scope. I actually don't have much idea about this.
I have tried to search this but I wasn't able to find a proper solution on my requirement.

I want to use some PHP code inside my iOS application.
Is it possible that I add some PHP code files inside my iOS app and call these files functions as per my requirement.

Hope this will give you an idea about my requirement.

Let me know if I need to put some more light on it.

Comment: This is probably double-post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825219/can-i-wrap-php-code-from-my-website-in-c-to-build-an-ios-app

Comment: Can you put a car inside a car? No you can't. Hence you cannot use PHP in a native application as long as there is no PHP parser to parse the code.